# Stumped again with box in a box, this time with full color and a border

Tags: html, css

I asked in a previous post about centering a box in a box, but this time it got a bit weird. I tried 2 different codes. One with background-color and the other just using a border. It seems that the border aligns just fine, but the one with background color does not; although both have the same code. I'll provide it below. So now I am trying to center the background color one. Why is it that background color behave differently?

And why is there so much space on the top of the first box? And how would I center the box perfectly for the full colored body one?

```
<div id="box1">
    <div class="midbox"></div>
</div>
<div id="test1">
    <div class="testbox"></div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
#box1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.midbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin:130px auto;
}
#test1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:solid black 3px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.testbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 130px auto;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZjuP/)

Answer (score 0):

the issue in case of #box1 is due to `collapsing margins`

> only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be
>   honoured, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin
>   value will be collapsed to zero.
>
> If you apply padding or a border to the parent container then both
>   margins will be honoured:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

see this section:

> Collapsing Margins Between Parent and Child Elements

also see this for an example:

http://www.garethredfern.com/articles/css-margin-collapse